# Line translation and like それこそ普通はためらうような

Tags: translation

This is internal monologue of a character about another. Also this is from a manga so there is no punctuation.

> この子は時々まるで『自分』を省みないような
>
> それこそ普通はためらうような… 命を投げ出す行為を平気でしてまう

This is my current interpretation:

> This girl sometimes seems like she doesn’t care about “herself” at all.
>
> That for sure is how she normally is, seemingly hesitant…
> about actions that completely and remorselessly sacrifice lives.

The second bit is a bit dubious. It is characteristic of the character being described, since she never hives up on people, it still feels weird in context.

On the grammatical/language side I'm assuming それこそ普通 is basically saying that she is like that normally こそ is intensifying this but Im' not 100% sure since I haven't encountered それこそ before.

Also I'm not sure what's being described as ためらうような hesitating like? How it's normally?

And of course what's your read on this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is one long sentence. "まるで自分を省みないような", "それこそ普通はためらうような" and "命を投げ出す" all modify 行為. The basic structure is:

> この子は時々<long modifier here>行為をしてしまう
>   This girls sometimes commit (such-and-such) an act.

And...

- まるで自分を省みないような行為: an act that looks as if she were entirely ignoring herself
- それこそ普通はためらうような行為: the very act which people usually hesitate to do
- 命を投げ出す行為: an act of abandoning one's life
- 平気で: without deeply thinking, with no compunction, innocently

それこそ is a set expression meaning "exact(ly)", "just", "very", "none other than", etc.

Comment: Ahhh. If the last can apply to her own life than that does make sense...
Damn the lack of punctuation, it makes the context problem even harder.