# Use of ちょうズレる in a sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, interpretation

Context: Dirrect continuation of text in [previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58594/line-translation-and-like-%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%82%89%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA).

> 誰かを守りたいとかそういった『意志』や
>   『自己犠牲』的な感情ともちょうズレる

Since the speaker is Kansai, at first I thought these were two separate sentences and that や was Kansai だ. But now I think it is just and.

The thing that mostly confuses me, and the reason I'm posting this is the last bit ちょうズレる. For one if you trust the Japanese-English dictionaries it's something like: very/really a bit off/deviant/off. Which didn't make much sense to me because putting an intensifier and a word that means little of something together doesn't make much sense (very a bit off) and ズレる entries in English dictionaries didn't seem to fit.

Now I THINK, after checking the [Japanese definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120599/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%BA%E3%83%AC%E3%82%8B/), it means more something non/standard, something that stands out and deviates from norm. Using very and something deviating from norm a bit together still feels strange, but I think the speaker is probably saying that such (level of) feelings as these (self sacrifice and determination to want to save) IS REALLY out of the ordinary. And so this is my curent translation of that line.

> Both her determination to protect someone 
>   and her willingness to sacrifice herself are out of the ordinary.

My question is am I right in my interpretation, and if anyone can explain to me why use ちょう and ズレる together when I'm guessing Japanese probably has other words for something being out of the ordinary without the implication of it being a BIT out of the ordinary.

Edit:

Some have gone looking for the original source. Just to clarify, I haven't yet tried to parse the rest of the comment, what I'm trying to figure out does not come from that page. That page is talking about the same manga, but that's not how it was said in the original. The following is the text in the original manga panel and is identical to what I typed I think.

[image: The actual source]

Comment: Are you sure it's ちょう rather than ちょっと, ちょい or something?

Comment: ^ 「～ともちょうズレる」より「～～ともちょっとズレる」とかのほうが自然な感じしますよね・・・@4th ソースここですか？　⇒ http://vfyf.blog33.fc2.com/blog-entry-1942.html  「自分を省みないようなそれこそ普通ならためらうような命を投げ出す行為を平気でしてしまう、誰かを守りたいとかそういった『意志』や『自己犠牲』的な感情とも**ちょっとズレている** 。」になってますね。

Comment: @Chocolate That is close, but is not my actual source. I have edited my post to add the image of the actual text. I don't think I made mistakes typing it over.

Comment: オリジナルは、関西弁のかたのインタビューの書き起こしでしょうか？私の見つけたページは全て関東弁で書かれていましたが。関西弁では「ちょっと」のことをしばしば「ちょう」って言うんで。eg ちょっと待って(関東弁) → ちょー待って(関西弁)

Comment: @Chocolate Oh yeah. Like in couple previous questions of mine, this is from an internal monologue by a Kansai speaker about another.
So ちょっと = ちょう (Kansai)? I WAS wondering of some Kansai fun was happening. So this is just stressing how little the difference is.

Comment: @Chocolate それだー＞＜

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>So, as @Chocolate pointed out, it's ちょっとズレている, not ちょうズレる. Hiragana ちょう is too informal/comical in a serious analytic statement like this, and it does not semantically fit the previous context, either.</del> <del>(**EDIT**: Okay, the original source indeed says ちょうズレる, and this ちょう should mean とても here. I'm not the only native speaker who felt this ちょう was unnatural, but let's forget this for now. I don't know who said this, after all.)</del> **EDIT 2**: Looks like this is a sentence from a Kansai-ben speaker....Then this ちょう (often also written as ちょー, ちょお) should be a kansai slangy version of ちょっと.

In general, while ズレる tends to refer to a small but significant difference, it's also perfectly fine to say すごくズレている, 大幅にズレた and so on. Please don't take that "a bit" part too literally.

ズレる without と can mean "different from the norm", but in this case there is [と that marks the target of a comparison](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52564/5010). ～とズレている is simply "to be (a little) different from ～".

The sentence roughly means "(Her behavior pattern) is also a little different from 'will to protect someone' or 'self-sacrifice'". This also aligns with the previous context. This person thinks her behavior is different from 自己犠牲, because the word 犠牲 means giving up something important to her. Her life is so unimportant to her that she does not think she is sacrificing something. In other words, she is acting somewhat like a heartless robot that does not understand the meaning of life.

Comment: Even though this "her actual behavior is different from what one might expect someone self sacrificing to have" could work in other dirrection, if it's possible. The character being talked about is actually normally waaaaayy cheerfull. Which one might not expect from someone with willing and determined to save people even if it means giving up her life, which she'll do without any hesitation.
**BUT**, I do wonder, what makes you think this sentence means the behavior pattern is different from determination and self sacrifice?

Comment: Okay, so "robot" was maybe an overstatement. But "different from self-sacrifice" is exactly what this sentence says. This ズレる never means "extraordinary" for the reason I already wrote in my answer. Regarding ちょう, I still feel this is a peculiar mixture of casual and serious expressions (that's why someone rephrased it to ちょっとズレている). Maybe an upbeat character who is trying to think something deeply might say something like this.

Comment: Yes, the person thinking/saying this is an upbeat Kansai person hence that instead of ちょっと as @Chocolate noted.
So literally it's "A bit different from feelings like self sacrifice and determination.".
I'm assuming you think the bit that is different from this is the behavior of person being described? Context I guess?